# CodeIgniter session help, cookies not secure?

Tags: security, session, codeigniter, cookies

I'm just getting into learning about sessions, and for my purposes, I want to create something that upon every request from the client, the server authenticates that user, and only then performs data-handling for that user.

However, I have seen a lot of examples with CodeIgniter where the session is set up as thus:

```
$this->load->library('session');

$newdata = array(
               'username'  => 'johndoe',
               'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
               'logged_in' => TRUE
           );

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

However, couldn't someone just create a cookie on their computer with a common username and the 'logged_in' state to true, and suddenly you're authenticated without a password?  This seems like a security flaw to me, but I see so many examples like this.

What is the proper way to authenticate the user on each request?

Comment: Wondering the same thing: why doesn't CI just use php sessions and provide some kind of CI-ish interface to it? It is true that you can use the database, but what's wrong with 'normal' sessions in the first place?

Comment: Codeigniter session library is there to make sessions more fexible, and take the work out of handling sessions.  It does work very well and if you store the sessions in the database forces validation of a unique session ID.  Codeigniter handles transparently both the setting and checking of the session id.  There is an interface to native sessions for codigniter here: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Native_session/

Comment: "Session" does not mean "Cookie". Session only exists on the server, and out-of-direct-reach of an attacker. The Cookie just contains a sessionid, which is an opaque and random string. The server uses the sessionid to lookup the session object for the current user. In short, the cookie does not contain the user name/email/logged_in flags, and hence an attacker cannot modify them directly

Comment: @sri: that's just not true for codeigniter.

Comment: @Daniel - Thanks for the note. I just read http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html, and you are right - CodeIgniter handles session differently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the application/config/config.php file of your codigniter install you can choose to encrypt your cookies.

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']  = 7200;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;  // set from false to TRUE
```

Once this is set the set_userdata() and userdata() methods will transparently handle encrypting and decrypting the session data.

A full list of codigniter session config options is at the bottom of this page:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Alright, that sounds good.  The only thing I wonder is this as secure as storing session data in a database?  If someone cracks the cookie encryption, they can now forge a cookie for any user (guessing usernames) instead of just accessing one user's account.

Comment: If it is a concern, why don't you use the database to store sessions? This way you can validate session ID's in addition to having the cookie encrypted. If you are concerned with security, you indeed *should* be using the database. See *Saving Session Data to a Database* section of the CI user guide: http://demos.softaculous.com/CodeIgniter/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like increased security, you can choose to store session data in the database by modifying the following lines within your CodeIgniter `config.php`:

```
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
```

Then, simply create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(16) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

Comment: A nice explanation here: http://christopherickes.com/web-app-development/3-codeigniter-sessions-best-practices/ which also suggests changing: $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session'; to $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'cisession'; for IE compatibility